# JavaFX TreeView with unique Strings

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

I want a `javaFx` `TreeView` having unique string labels with a very large list of Strings.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    myTreeView.setRoot(new TreeItem());
    myTreeView.setShowRoot(false);
}

public void addUniqueItem(String item) {
    List<TreeItem> treeNodes = myTreeView.getRoot().getChildren();

    if (!treeNodes.contains(item)) {
        treeNodes.add(new TreeItem<>(item));
        treeNodes.sort((o1, o2) -> ((String)o1.getValue()).compareTo((String)o2.getValue()));
    }
}
```

Now this `addUniqueItem` is not working. Because,
`treeNodes.contains(item)` returns always false as the types are mismatched.

So I have three questions.

> 1. How to correct the `contains` function here.
> 2. As it's a list I am getting from `myTreeView.getRoot().getChildren()` the contains is O(n) search,
>      hence can be very slow. How can I make it faster by making it a `Set`
>      or any other `container`?
> 3. I think my whole approach is wrong. How do I implement a `TreeView` which can add a string node uniquely?

```
--ROOT
----CH1
----CH5
.......
----CH10
```

Now adding `CH1` again, would not change anything.

**Edit:** A temporary working solution is that I kept a replica copy of the same names in a `HashSet` and searched there to find that it already exists or not. then updated the `TreeView` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

1. > How to correct the contains function here.

By using Stream you can easily write your own contains method like that

```
if(treeNodes.stream().noneMatch(treeItem -> item.equals(treeItem.getValue())
```

2. > As it's a list I am getting from myTreeView.getRoot().getChildren() the contains is O(n) search, hence can be very slow. How can I make it faster by making it a Set or any other container?

You are right contains method need to iterate the list hence an O(n) complexity.
Using an HashSet for example will give you O(1) complexity.

But don't build a Set and then search on it each time you call your addUniqItem method. Because you will need to iterate the list to construct the set and then search the set.

So you can add a field in your class like that :

```
private Set<String> uniqItemSet = new HashSet<>();
```

and use it like that :

```
    public void addUniqueItem(String item) {

    if (uniqItemSet.add(item)) {
        treeNodes.add(new TreeItem<>(item));
        treeNodes.sort((o1, o2) -> ((String)o1.getValue()).compareTo((String)o2.getValue()));
    }
}
```

3. > I think my whole approach is wrong. How do I implement a TreeView which can add a string node uniquely?

You are on the right way as your edit message says. But maybe you are looking for a [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html) since you are building a tree without hierarchy.

Edit: thx fabian for the improvement

Comment: You only need a single method call for a set method in the `addUniqueItem` method: `if (uniqItemSet.add(item)) { treeNodes.add...}`

Comment: I need a tree, hierarchy was not added for keeping it simple. Yeah works for now. Thanks for the answer.